# How to ping in linux until host is known with X seconds timeout?

Tags: linux, bash, ping

Im trying to wait for a device to boot up in my code and i dont want to use sleep to wait for him.
my problem is that sometimes the device fail to boot and im stuck in a loop when using:

```
until ping -c1 www.google.com &>/dev/null; do :; done
while true; do ping -c1 www.google.com > /dev/null && break; done
```

How can i try to ping to the device for X seconds and print "DEAD" or "ALIVE" using one liner?

Comment: For the record, this seems to been already answered here: https://serverfault.com/questions/200468/how-can-i-set-a-short-timeout-with-the-ping-command

Comment: For the record it didnt answer my question, i need 1 liner with timeout and a print without using external tools Im guessing its not pisiable withous script or external tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `-W` option that keeps `ping` waiting for a timeout of `X` seconds.

For Linux (iputils):

```
$ ping -c1 -W10 <url>
```

For MacOS X:

```
$ ping -c1 -t10 <url>
```

Not a one-liner, but this would wait for 10 seconds before timing out:

```
if ping -c 1 -W 10 www.google.com 1>/dev/null; then 
    echo Success; 
else 
    echo Failed; 
fi
```

Comment: Tried the if as one liner and answer my needs, thanks !

Comment: Does not work for me. It will give me the correct answer if the device is in the same state (reachable or not) the whole time. But if it starts out as unreachable and then becomes reachable in the middle of the wait period, it does not succeed. It just waits the whole time and then evaluates as a failure.

Comment: Ah, the issue is that you actually need the lowercase `-w` flag rather than the uppercase `-W` flag.

Comment: Er nope, never mind, still not quite right... frustrating.

Comment: As @WhittlesJr said, this answer cannot address the case when the host becomes up in the middle, e.g. the in OP's "wait for a device to boot up" case. Since the device is not booted, the test need keep sending out probe packets, hence `-c 1` is not working. In fact neither the upper case `-W` nor the lower case `-w` option, nor their combinations with or without `-c` option works. Instead, @Pavlo Hrybok's answer works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this linux utility: https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout
And your oneliner would be something like this:

```
timeout 50 bash -c "while true; do if ping -c1 -i1 8.8.8.8 &>/dev/null; then echo "up"; break; fi; done"
```

Comment: In fact, this is answer can address OP's "wait for a device to boot up" need. I think this should be the accepted one. Up vote.